# Where is Passbook for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, wallet

I installed iOS 6 on my iPad and went looking for Passbook and didn't find it. I checked the AppStore and no results are found for Passbook.

Where is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### **Passbook**

is only for the iPhone and iPod Touch. The following is taken from the **[official description](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#passbook)**:

> ...you can scan your **iPhone or iPod** touch to check in for a flight, get into a movie, and redeem a coupon....

Comment: Must have missed that in the release notes. Thanks.

Comment: No prob. It would be really funny if people started paying for their coffee at Starbucks using iPads. I could expect it to become normal just like taking pictures/videos with the iPad has become somewhat common.

Comment: I thought it was more an app for keeping track of all of the various frequent buyer cards, etc. Thought maybe to enter them on the iPad and then have it sync with the phone. Wasn't really thinking of scanning them.

Answer (score 7):

Passbook is only available on iPhone and iPod touch.